# How can I iterate over my Enumeration values that contain a particular value?

Tags: scala

I have an enumeration that currently for some reason is not outputting anything when I loop over the values:

```
 object UserType extends Enumeration {
    type UserType = UTValue

    protected case class UTValue(name: String, roles: Set[String]) extends super.Val {
     // override def toString(): String = name
    }

    val anonymous = UTValue("anonymous", Set.empty)
    val superUser = UTValue("super", Set("member", "admin", "edit", "delete"))
  }

  println(UserType.anonymous)
  println(UserType.superUser)
  println(UserType.values.map(println))
```

The output is:

```
anonymous
superUser
anonymous
superUser
TreeSet(())
```

Why is an empty TreeSet(()) being returned?

**My main question:   How can I iterate over all the Enumeration values that contain the role "member".**

```
UserType.values.filter(_.roles.contains("member"))
```

(scala 2.13.x)

Answer (score 2):

You are printing value inside the map and println returns Unit, if you remove println inside the map like `println(UserType.values.map(value => value))`

```
 object UserType extends Enumeration {
    type UserType = UTValue

    protected case class UTValue(name: String, roles: Set[String]) extends super.Val {
      // override def toString(): String = name
    }

    val anonymous = UTValue("anonymous", Set.empty)
    val superUser = UTValue("super", Set("member", "admin", "edit", "delete"))
  }

  println(UserType.anonymous)
  println(UserType.superUser)
  println(UserType.values.map(x => x))
```

And since it is TreeSet it removes duplicate values and keeps only one Unit value (), that is why you are getting `TreeSet(())`

Answer (score 1):

You need `implicit conversion` in `UserType`.

```
object UserType extends Enumeration {
    type UserType = UTValue

    protected case class UTValue(name: String, roles: Set[String]) extends super.Val {
        // override def toString(): String = name
    }

    val anonymous = UTValue("anonymous", Set.empty)
    val superUser = UTValue("super", Set("member", "admin", "edit", "delete"))

    import scala.language.implicitConversions
    implicit def valueToUTValue(x: Value): UTValue = x.asInstanceOf[UTValue]
}

UserType.values.filter(_.roles.contains("member")).foreach(println)
```